# App Signing for Android with VS2022 for Mac

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, ad-hoc-distribution, android-app-signing

Whenever i try to sign my Xamarin forms app for Android to Ad-hoc distribution, i get the below message in "Sign and Distribute" window of VS2022 for Mac.

**"Did not properly detect signing algorithm, falling back to default (RSA)"**

I have the keystore file created with new key.

- java --version gives below

  ```
   openjdk 11.0.16.1 2022-08-12 LTS
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-40648 (build 11.0.16.1+1-LTS)
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-40648 (build 11.0.16.1+1-LTS, mixed mode)
  ```
- VS 2022

  ```
   Visual Studio 2022 for Mac version 17.6
  ```
- Xamarin forms

  ```
   5.0.0.2578
  ```

Edit : I followed the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/?tabs=macos)

Comment: You can refer to the official doc about [Ad-hoc distribution on Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/?tabs=macos) and this: [Finding your Keystore's Signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/keystore-signature?tabs=macos).

Comment: @jianwei-sun-msft this is where i'm stuck... I followed the official documentation you mentioned above too. And couldn't find any youtube tutorial for this issue so far.

Comment: I see the same RSA fall-back warning, but it is not affecting my ability to publish Android apps. My environment is VS2022 Mac Community (version 17.6), Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2622, Ventura 13.6.3.  I created my signing key a few years ago.

Comment: I managed to sign several apps with the locally created cert for adhoc distribution, on my Mac. Then I started getting the same signing error as you. Seems the keystore got corrupt, somewhere along the way.
Did you ever get this resolved?